# How can I use multiple conditions (and, or) in thymeleaf th:if

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, logical-operators

When I use thymeleaf `th:if`, I want to sum this code:

```
th:if=${lang.equals('A') or lang.equals('B')}.
```

I use `||`, the "or", but it is not used.

It works in spring framework, thymeleaf:

```
th:if=${lang.equals('A')
th:if=${lang.equals('B')
```

I want to sum this code.

```
th:if=${lang.equals('A') or lang.equals('B')}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them

```
th:if="${lang == 'A' OR lang == 'B'}"
```

Comment: missing double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Try this one (PS-  Please ensure that you're putting the double-inverted commas carefully in starting and ending )

```
th:if="${lang=='A'} and ${lang=='B'}"
```

Comment: oh..! Thanks!! i missed double quotes :(

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you out, so it could help others facing the same issue as well